# control m enterprise batch prints complete script in sysouts?

Tags: shell, logging, batch-processing, control-m

I'm using control M enterprise application to manage batch jobs. While I execute a batch shell script from control M it prints the complete script code along with the output. Is there a way to avoid printing that? The actual problem is that, by printing the compile code everyone can see the DB credentials in the log. Please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by adding set +x in the top of the script. set +x will show the running command in bash script. Similarly set -x will disable printing it. for more details [set-x usage](http://stefaanlippens.net/set-x)